# Eclipse & Intellij DE - Unable to connect to mysql database

Tags: java, mysql

I followed the instructions of downloading the connector driver (version 8.0.19) of MYSQL database (5.1) and getting connected to eclipse IDE(13 version), but shows the error message as

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/employee
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:700)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:258)
at jdbcdemo.Driver.main(Driver.java:14
```

I first downloaded the driver connector jar file and saved it in the folder.
I tired every possible options in Eclipse and Intellij IDE, but failed to connect.
Do I need to set up anything such as environment variables in advanced system settings under control panel home?

Please could you help me with this connection?

Comment: could you check if driver jar is added to classpath?

Comment: Could you explain how we do we add driver jar to the classpath? I would like to verify if I have done in the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

Create a 'lib' folder inside the project folder, and put the Jar file in there. You then need to tell eclipse to include it in your classpath so your code will compile and run inside eclipse.

To do that: - Go into the properties of your project - Select 'Java Build Path' in the left-hand column - select the 'Libraries' tab in the centre part of the window - Click the Add JARs button - this will give you a list of your projects in eclipse - expand your project and into the lib folder - your jar will be there. - Select the JAR, click OK, and OK again out of the properties window.

Or, you can just right-click the jar and click BuildPath->Add to Build Path.

Reference: [how to setup JDBC in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10882475/how-to-setup-jdbc-in-eclipse)

Comment: I created a 'lib' folder inside the project folder. Then copied and pasted the jar files in the lib folder. The entered the class path by selecting the properties to my project and added the file after clicking the JAR button. Also tried doing the alternative, but found the driver file there too. After doing all the steps, I find the same error a mentioned earlier. Interestingly, I tried doing the similar steps on Intellij IDE just to check the other IDE, but I get the same error. Is there anything else I am missing, such as addling classname under advanced system setting?

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using Java language to access database, then make sure you use the following statement before opening the connection:
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

Try if it works.

Comment: Shall I include cj to this - Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"); Not sure, just trying all options. Do I need to enter/enter any classname under advanced system setting?

Comment: Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
- this should work for MySql. Please check the link https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html . Please make sure that the driver jars are in classpath.